# Convert a combined Date and Time String to long value?

Tags: android, datetime, datetimepicker

I am trying to get long value of a string (date & time string), but it is not working. What I am trying to do is:

- Choose date form *datepicker* and store it in a String
- Choose time from *timepicker* and store it in a String

Then I concatenate these two strings and get long value from that string.

I have tried a few Date formatters but I am unable to get this done. The format of my string is `dd-MM-yyy h:mm a`. Please help me out of this. Provide any utility available for this.

Comment: If you have the date/time picker values, why bother going through strings?

Comment: because I have to get that long value, which when I get convert to date, gives me date with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about strings, and go directly with the values:

```
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById...
TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById...

Date timeStamp = new Date( dp.getYear(), dp.getMonth(), dp.getDay(), tp.getHour(), tp.getMinute(), 0 );

long longTime = timeStamp.getTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy h:mm a");
Date myDate = new Date(); // Default Value.
try {
        myDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
        // Do Something on Error.
}
Long dateTimeinLong = myDate.getTime();
```

where `dateString` is your concatenated String of date and time.

Comment: And don't forget to put parse() into try - catch block. :)